# Not able to understand python function of cosine similarity

Tags: python, numpy, math, linear-algebra, cosine-similarity

I am working through the example in the [blog](http://blog.ethanrosenthal.com/2015/11/02/intro-to-collaborative-filtering/) to understand collaborative filter method used in recommendation system.I came across cosine similarity expressed as

[image]

In python using numpy its written as

```
def similarity(ratings, kind='user', epslion=1e-9):
      if kind == 'user' :
         sim = ratings.dot(ratings.T)
      elif (kind=='item'):
          sim = ratings.T.dot(ratings) + epslion
      norms = np.array([np.sqrt(np.diagonal(sim))])

      return  (sim / norms / norms.T )
```

> Questions

1. what is the math behind calculation of the norm in the code
2. how does `(sim / norms / norms.T )` equals to `` sim(u,u`) `` in the equation

Thanks in advance for your time – if I’ve missed out anything, over- or under-emphasized a specific point let me know in the comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ratings are stored in the numpy matrix `ratings`, where rows correspond to users (index `u`), while columns correspond to items (index `i`). Since you want to calculate `sim(u, u')`, i.e., the similarity between users, let's assume below that `kind = 'user'`.

Now, let's have a look first on `r_{ui}r_{u'i}` without the square-root scaling factors. This expression is summed over `i` which can be interpreted as matrix multiplication of `r` with the transpose of `r`, i.e.:

```
\sum_i r_{ui}r_{u'i} = \sum_i r_{ui}(r^T)_{iu'} =: s_{uu'}
```

As done already above, let's denote the resulting matrix as `s` (variable `sim` in the code). This matrix is by definition symmetric and its rows/columns are labeled with the "user" indices `u/u'`.

Now, the scaling "factor" `f_{u} := \sqrt\sum_i r^2_{ui}` is in fact a vector indexed with `u` (each item of which is the Euclidean norm of the corresponding row of the matrix `r`). However, having constructed `s_{uu'}`, we can see that `f_{u}` is nothing else than `\sqrt s_{uu}`.

Finally, the similarity factor of interest is `s_{uu'}/f{u}/f{u'}`. The posted code calculates this for all indices `u/u'` and returns the result as a matrix. To this end, it:

1. calculates `sim` (the matrix `s` above) as `ratings.dot(ratings.T)`
2. gets the square root of its diagonal (the vector `f` above) as `np.sqrt(np.diagonal(sim))`
3. to do the row/column scaling of `s` in an efficient way, this is then expressed as a two-dimensional array `norms = np.array([np.sqrt(np.diagonal(sim))])` (note the missing `[]` in your post)
4. finally, the matrix `s_{uu'}/f{u}/f{u'}` is calculated as `sim / norms / norms.T`. Here, since `norms` has shape `(1, num_of_users)`, the first division does the column scaling, while the division with `norms.T` scales the rows.